# Binding OxyPlot Tracker and set getting value in TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, oxyplot

Project - WPF, C#, IDE - Visual Studio. I want bind value traking on my *PlotView*. My code XAML:

```
 <Border CornerRadius="6" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <oxy:PlotView Background="White" Model="{Binding GraphicModel.Model}"  >

        </oxy:PlotView>
    </Border>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding CurrentTrackerValue}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

I know, what PlotView.Model have event *TrackerChange*. How using this event?
P.S.: I use pattern MVVM, so i want using command instead event. Thank!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to update a TextBlock each time the Tracker is updated. I believe you were right on track with the TrackerChanged event. You could do the following in your ViewModel, where you are creating the PlotModel instance, which would be bound to the OxyPlot Graph

```
PlotModelName.TrackerChanged += (sender, eventArgs)=>
{
  CurrentTrackerValue = eventArgs.HitResult != null ? eventArgs.HitResult.Text : CurrentTrackerValue;
  NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentTrackerValue));
};
```

Where CurrentTrackerValue is defined as

```
public string CurrentTrackerValue { get; set; }
```

This would ensure the CurrentTrackerValue property is updated each time Tracker is changed via the TrackerChangedEvent

Comment: Thank you behind your answer! But, i use pattern mvvm, so i want replace event to the commanded. This possibly?

Comment: The above example uses MVVM Pattern. above change has to be done in your ViewModel, where you are create the PlotModel

Comment: In above example, PlotModelName is the PlotModel instance to which your Oxyplot graph is bound to. So when you add series to it, you are also adding a custom event for TrackerChanged. In the event, you update a Property called CurrentTrackerValue, which is bound to your TextBlock

Comment: Sorry, i am novice in mvvm, so i thought, what instead events using commands. This incorrectly?

Comment: @Range You dont need ICommand here. Your current Xaml fits well. You would need to add the above code to the place where you create the PlotModel, which bound in Oxyplot

Comment: @Range Glad to help you. Kindly mark it as Answer if it helped you resolve the issue so that it can be helpful for others as well.

Answer (score 1):

guys thanks it works steps bellow :)

.NET 4.7.2

1. I added `INotifyPropertyChanged` and

```
      public string CurrentTrackerValueX { get; set; }
      public string CurrentTrackerValueY { get; set; }
```

2. then generate

```
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null) 
    { 
    PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); 
    }
```

3. then i follow your idea

```
    pm.TrackerChanged += (sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        string CurrentTrackerValue = "";
        CurrentTrackerValue = eventArgs.HitResult != null ? eventArgs.HitResult.Text : CurrentTrackerValue;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(CurrentTrackerValue))
        {
            var x = Regex.Matches(CurrentTrackerValue, "([0-9]*,[0-9]*)");
            CurrentTrackerValueX = x[0].Value;
            CurrentTrackerValueY = x[1].Value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentTrackerValueX));
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(CurrentTrackerValueY));
        }
    };
```

`If loop` is needed cause of null value in textbox after leaving Tracker, he still want gives null to textbox.

All done and works with this type of string :)

```
    editcurrentLineSeries[i].TrackerFormatString = "{0}\n{1}: {2:0.00}\n{3}: {4:0.00}";
```